# JAX-WS error while writing package-info: could not create parent directories

Tags: java, soap, java-8, jax-ws

I am trying using `wsimport` to generate SOAP webservice from WSDL file
My OS is Window10, when i run cmd command

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin>wsimport -s C:\test\example\soap -p com.lordofthering.jaxws.server.topdown C:\test\gandalf.wsdl

I get error

> ...\package-info.java:1: error: error while writing package-info: could not create parent directories
> @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:somethingfunny:types", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
> ^
> 1 error
> compilation failed, errors should have been reported

I to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issues by open `cmd command prompt` as Administration right

Comment: In my case I also had jdk installed into the system folder C:\Program Files\Java\, and I didn't have admin rights. I just installed jdk into non-system folder and was able to use wsimport tool. I also tested my solution in SoapUI as well - helped.